# How to hide the DOM element using Jquery - Not duplicate

Tags: jquery

Its not duplicate, I am not understanding how to proceed with this.
I am new to JQuery please help me with how do I hide the one of the DOM element, Kindly refer my Image 1 (Actual UI) and Image 2(DOM element which need to be hide).
NOTE:- All element in that  has same class name, so I have to be careful while hiding specific element Please help me.
DOM element - 
[Image1 - UI Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlYQy.jpg)
[Image2 - DOM element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjaKp.jpg)

This is the DOM element which I need to hide :-

```
 <label for="Shipper Organization ID">

   <input type="checkbox" value="2794">

   <span class="s-panel-label-text" id="Shipper Organization ID">Shipper Organization ID</span>

 </label>

</div>
```

Comment: And where is your jQuery? First you say *hide* - than you say *delete*... what are you after actually? **When** should it delete?

Comment: I have changed to Hide, thanks for the correction

Comment: You tried asking same question before but never answered clarification of how this specific element needs to be determined or what would trigger it being hidden or removed

Comment: Yes, you did not answered my **bolded** question. **When** should that happen? On what event? Should you go look after all checked checkboxes to determine the array of items to be hidden?..

Comment: Note that `for` of `<label>` should match id of the input and id's can't have spaces in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the input's value, taking it's **unique** (like sort of item ID), you could target that `value` **attribute** `[value=""]` and look for `.closest()` like:

```
function hideCheckboxRadioRow( id ) {
  $("[value='"+ id +"']").closest(".s-checkboxradio-row").hide();
}
```

and simply use it like:

```
hideCheckboxRadioRow( 2794 );
```

**Notice:** (thanks to @charlietfl)
 that you cannot have spaces inside the `for=""` attribute's value, since it refers to an input's ID - and **IDs cannot have spaces** (therefore being an invalid ID)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, I am able to do like this -   $("label[for='Shipper Organization ID']").hide();